# Detect public IP address from within Linux Azure VM

Tags: linux, centos, azure

I have created a Linux VM (Centos 8) on Azure cloud, with public IP (SKU Standard, Static).
I expect that this IP address to be discoverable within the Linux VM.

```
[admin@my-vm ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:48:56:f6:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::222:48ff:fe56:f69a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I expect the public IP to be listed here too, but only localhost and private IP appear.
The public IP definitely works, because I could run web server without any issue.

My question is, why is my public IP not visible from my VM?
Is my VM behind a NAT?

Thanks.